# Extracting value from JSON and passing to another ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, segue

I'm trying to extract a number (ageInDays) from the JSON, and then pass it to another View Controller.

If I print ageInDays, it prints the correct answer, but will return nil when I try and pass it to another VC, but if I pass a default value to another VC it passes with no issues.
I am using Alamofire, and SwiftyJSON

I've only included the networking, parsing, and sending portions.

Basically, the app tells you roughly how many days you have left to live according to statistical data (pretty much to scare me into doing more in general.)

```
var ageInDays = ""

//MARK: - Networking


func getAgeData(url: String){
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Yes! We have the data!")
                let AgeJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                self.updateAgeData(json: AgeJSON)
            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                self.warningLabel.text = "Sorry, connection issues."
            }
    }
}

//MARK: - JSON Parsing

func updateAgeData(json: JSON) {

    if let ageResult = json["remaining_life_expectancy"].double{
    let ageInDays = (String((ageResult) * 365))
        print(ageInDays)
    } else {
        warningLabel.text = "Error: parsing JSON"
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    viewController.ageFromSettings = ageInDays
}

@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    dateNowAsURL()
    if count > 0 {
        finalURL = "\(baseUrl)\(sex)\(URLcountry)\(URLdate)\(URLage)"
        print(finalURL)

        getAgeData(url: finalURL)
    }

    if ageInDays != ""{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendingAgeData", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue: You are missing the fact that the Alamofire request is ASYNCHRONE. Replace `getAgeData(url: finalURL)` with `getAgeData(url: finalURL); print("After getAgeData");` And check whereas `print("Yes! We have the data!")` is printed before or after. How to manage them: look for "Swift + Closure + Async".

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful! I made the change and the "Yes! We have the data!" was printed before the result was given. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There seem two problems with your code.

1) Your API call is asynchronous, so you are performing Segue before you get the API response. you should either implement a call-back function or write this line after you get the value.

```
self.updateAgeData(json: AgeJSON)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendingAgeData", sender: self)
```

2) Your variable "ageInDays". You are never assigning any value to that variable.  In updateAgeData() function you are creating a local variable. Your global variable is not getting that value.

Use it like this

```
self.ageInDays = (String((ageResult) * 365))
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems with my code:

1. Because Alamofire is asynchronous, I had to perform the segue after the data was brought back.
2. The biggest issue was actually making sure that the data sent via segue was in the form needed. In this case as an Int, and not a String.